# CustomerQuery ResponseStream was null or empty

Tags: vb.net, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am calling CustomerQuery by customer name in order to get the Id.  My code has been working for quite some time without any change.  Now, it is returning the IdsException 'ResponseStream was null or empty.'  Here is my code:

```
Dim CustomerQuery as new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CustomerQuery
CustomerQuery.Name = CustomerName
Dim qboCustomers as IEnumerable(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer) = CustomerQuery.ExecuteQuery(of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer)(context)
If qboCustomers.Count>0 then
    Return qboCustomers(0).Id.Value
Else
    Return ""
End If
```

I believe the query should not be null or empty even if there is no match.  I think the count should just be 0.  Or, at least I believe it worked that way in the past.  Am I wrong?

Comment: You can try to capture the raw request XML using some tools like fiddler and use the same in ApiExplorer too see if it is working.

Comment: I tried playing with the data instead.  Originally the CustomerName that it was searching for was 'N22222 90996-1 SARABANDA AVIATION'.  After removing the 90996-1 from the customer name, it then gave me the expected response with 0 customers instead of the IDs Exception.  What was wrong with the previous customer name that caused it to throw the error?  Did it not like the hyphen in the customer name?

Answer (score 1):

Special chars in queries causes exception. You need to handle them first.
Please see this solution for escaping special chars while querying in V3 services-
https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6582149

Comment: Your example shows escaping a quote.  There was no quote in the data.  Is the hyphen considered a special character that needs to be escaped?